# Emulator has cornered the whole android system

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[image]My Emulator was working fine. But recently the whole android system starts on the left top. I tried to delete the emulator files and reinstall it. But still No help. How Can I reset it so that I can work on it? thanks.